# How to auto start the weinre server on a linux server

Tags: node.js, weinre

weinre is a debugger for web pages, like FireBug (for FireFox) and Web Inspector (for WebKit-based browsers), except it's designed to work remotely, and in particular, to allow you debug web pages on a mobile device such as a phone.

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html

Comment: This heavily depends on your operating system.

Comment: @TheHippo I use CentOS

Answer (score 1):

I used answer from https://serverfault.com/questions/496169/running-node-js-at-boot, but modified it a little bit:
https://gist.github.com/akuryan/aa458edd325ff840eb97

Modify it so that your User is correct and could launch weinre and have write access to LOG_FILE and LOCK_FILE

Hope, this would help you